# Access the water in young coconuts

Tags: supermarket

My supermarket sells young coconuts, looks similar to that one:

[image]

If you cut the top of the soft shell to the inner stone (a hard shell which contains the water). There you can find a soft point in the harder shell, big enough to pierce through with a drinking straw. How they create this soft point under "soft shell"?

Comment: Why is this off topic? OP might use the answers to make sure they can make something like this on their own. It's not obvious

Comment: @DSR Robert Cartaino keeps putting my questions on hold too. He has no idea what's he's doing and he doesn't understand the concept of a lifehack.

Comment: Put the coconut on its side so the top bit is pointing in the horizontal direction. Using an axe, cleaver or machete you can chop of a lot of the soft part of the top. To obtain the small hole you talk about you need make the same chopping motion as if to chop off a thin slice off of the top. That might take a few tries but eventually you see some of the white flesh. Use a straw to pierce through that and you have it.